# Problem with lagged covariates

Tags: time-series, survival

Suppose we have a binary variable $X$ that indicates whether a person ate pizza during the week. This variable is recorded for an entire year. So we have $X_{1}, \dots, X_{52}$ values (1 or 0).  Suppose I am interested in the number of weeks of the last 4 weeks that a person did not eat pizza. I want to use this to predict that hazard of a heart attack this week. Call this variable $Y$.

Then would $Y = 4-(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4)$ where $\text{week} > 4$?

Note that if we treat $X$ as an array based on time then $X_1 = X[\text{week}-1]$, $X_2 = X[\text{week}-2]$, $X_3 = X[\text{week}-3]$ and $X_4 = X[\text{week}-4]$ since we are working with lagged covariates.

Comment: Do you mean that, at time $t$, $Y_t = 4-(X_{t-1} + X_{t-2} + X_{t-3} + X_{t-4})$? This would be well defined for times $>5$. (Analysis of how it is associated with heart attack incidence is perhaps best asked in another question)

Comment: @guest: Why for times > 5?

Comment: Sorry, should be $\geq 5$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @mbq: See the second to last sentence.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have a series of dummies representing #times ate pizza in last 4 weeks, ranging from `1time` to `4times`? The omitted reference would be that they didn't eat any pizza in the last 4 weeks. Is there a reason not to use a series of dummy variables?